# Why most flutter web packages are developed using the js package?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I want to develop a flutter web package and noticed that many [flutter web packages](https://pub.dev/packages?q=dependency%3Ajs) are depended on the [js package](https://pub.dev/packages/js). Is it the best way to develop web apps as for now? Can someone who has developed web packages guide me on this?

Comment: depends on what you want to achieve , if it can be done via pure dart awesome else whatever works for you . example plugin i created https://pub.dev/packages/hexcolor  web,ios,android ,mcos,linux

Comment: Did you develop this package using only dart?

Comment: Yeah ... Pure dart

Comment: Nice. I want to authenticate users with identity providers such as facebook, google (not limited to just google and facebook) . I have found packages that work in mobile but they don't work in web. So I was wondering if using js was the best way out as for now. Thanks for this perspective @griffins

Comment: Firebase Auth for web supports lots of Auth methods ... Else you can always create a dart wrapper around an Auth provider API / the normal way you would handle API calls

Comment: Yes. I checked firebase but it does not have all the platforms I need. So for some I will have to write custom code. I will try the second option you suggested with the dart wrapper. Thanks for it.

Comment: @griffins https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62471919/flutter-facebook-login-in-web This was one of the problems I faced when I tried facebook recently.

Comment: What if Facebook login with firebase should work out of the box

Comment: What if Facebook login with firebase should work out of the box

Comment: I am not quite sure why this problem exists with web only. Out of the box like?

Comment: out of the box ..should work "easily" did you setup your flutter web correctly... https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup